# Importing Excel data into SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Below SQL Query is fine when I execute in SQL Server 2008 but it is not working in SQL Server 2005.

```
SELECT * INTO "12-2014" FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\ImportExcel\Test.xls', ['12-2014$'])
```

I am getting this error.

`Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1`
`The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.`

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

this [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4be2d105-9c7d-43e6-99e8-bc0a6657ddef/the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-systemdata?forum=sqldataaccess) should help you.

essentially this:

> First, I want to inform that, Import and Export Data (32-bit) is the
>   default export tool when you right click a database to export data.
>   Let’s perform the following steps to export data from SQL Server to
>   Excel with Import and Export Data (64-bit):
>
> 1. Click Start, All Programs, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 folder, Import and Export Data (64-bit).
> 2. In “Choose a Data Source” step, please choose “SQL Server Native Client” as Data source, and specify your Server name and Database,
>      then click next.
> 3. In “Choose a Destination” step, please choose “Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider”, and then click “Properties…”
> 4. In “Data Link Properties”, under “Connection” tab, please fill out the Date Source (the excel file location, for example:
>      D:\Temp\temp.xlsx); under “All” tab, please double click “Extended
>      Properties”, and input “Excel 12.0” (without quotation) as its
>      property value, return to “Connection” tab and click “Test Connection”
>      and we will receive a message stating the connection succeeded, click
>      “OK”.
> 5. Click “Next” until the step “Select Source Tables and Views”, please select the table you want to export there and then click
>      “Next”.
> 6. Follow the wizard and finish the process.
>
> You can also refer to the following link which shows how to import
>   data from Excel to SQL Server with screenshots:
>
> http://hrvoje.piasevoli.com/2010/09/01/importing-data-from-64-bit-excel-in-ssis/

Comment: Luschn thank you for your quick response, I have used SSIS/Import wizard but I am trying to write C# app which imports excel data into SQL. The code I sent is fine on server 2008 but not 2005. Do you think a different way of doing?